# Setting up GLEW with QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glew

I have a Problem Setting up GLEW in Qt, which i'm using with the Microsoft Visual C++ 2012-Compiler. Here is my class

```
#ifndef MYQOPENGLWIDGET_H
#define MYQOPENGLWIDGET_H

#define QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include <iostream>


class MyQOpenGLWidget : public QGLWidget{

public:
MyQOpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0): QGLWidget(parent){}

void initializeGL()
{



    GLenum err = glewInit();

    if(err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Error!", QString("Failed to initialize GLEW ") + reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glewGetErrorString(err)), QMessageBox::Yes );
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Success!", QString("Succeded to initialize GLEW! "), QMessageBox::Yes );

    }

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    std::cout << "Leaving initializeGL" << std::endl;
}

void paintGL()
{
    std::cout << "paintGL()" << std::endl;
}


void resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    if(h == 0)
      h=1;
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);

    std::cout << "resizeGL()" << std::endl;

    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

}

};

#endif // MYQOPENGLWIDGET_H
```

In my pro-file I succesfully link to GLEW (which is included in gltools.lib which Comes form the OpenGLSuperbible ) (By the way, the libraries I use here must be correct, because I have a working project that I created with Visual Studio and the same compiler.)

```
QT       += core gui widgets

QT += opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled2
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Users/fin/Documents/GLEWTEst/include"
LIBS += "C:/Users/fin/Documents/GLEWTEst/lib/gltools.lib"

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    myqopenglwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    ../build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Debug/debug/untitled2.exe
```

Now what happens is, the Programm starts, and initializes GLEW correctly and calls initializeGL(), resizeGL() and then paintGL() 
Then it says the Programm was terminated with Exit code 1.
So just a program Crash without any error message. Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing

```
QMessageBox::information(0, "Success!", QString("Succeded to initialize GLEW! "), QMessageBox::Yes );
```

from the code above. However I don't know why this is.